# Complex alignments of blocks

Tags: positioning, minipage, letters

How could the kind of layout below be achieved in LaTeX, without using a *letter* document class?

[image]

At first, I thought of tables, but it would be impossible to align the first line of the second block with the last one of the first block.

Thank you for any help or reference.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to begin your questions with a greeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{3cm}
1\\2\\3\\4\\5
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{3cm}
3\\4\\5
\end{minipage}\\
6\\7
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: And how can we do with the upper line of text (that could also be aligned with the first line of the first block if it's easier) ?

Comment: @Klaus: you use `[t]`in the options of the two minipages !

Comment: @Altermundus Sorry, I dont see how it would work and my experiments haven't been successfull. Could you give a little more details, please ?

Comment: @Klaus: `\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
first block ...`  and not `b`. You need to use `t` (t=top), now the blocks are aligned with the top of boxes. But you need to use `t` for the two minipages.

Comment: @Altermundus I think we misunderstood? I did not ask how to align the blocks with their first line, but how to add and align the "line of text" of my drawing.

Comment: I update the answer. With `minipage`, you can align blocks with any line.

Comment: @Klaus  yes we misunderstood but it's not easy tu understand what is the upper line of text? I don't understand what you want, but an idea it's perhaps to use minipages inside other minipage (nested minipages)